# System of equations in draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net, formatting, latex

I'm looking for a way to write a system of equations in draw.io. I know how to do it in latex, but it seems that the syntax is different in draw.io. Could you tell me how to do it please?

In latex I can use packages like `\usepackage{empheq}`:

```
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align*}
 &= \\
 &= 
\end{empheq}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
\begin{aligned}\tau_v \dot v &= f(\textbf v(t), \textbf w(t)) \\  \tau_w \dot w &= g(\textbf v(t), \textbf w(t))\end{aligned}
```

Note that there's no " ` " sign at the beginning or the end. Also, make sure that the mathematical typesetting is enabled from "Extras" menu.

Comment: Hello @arash thank you very much for your precious help.

Answer (score 1):

This article with examples might help you:
https://www.diagrams.net/doc/faq/math-typesetting

Best,

Comment: Hello @Marija thank you for the link; inside I didn't find an example about system of equations, can you write it in your answer please?

Comment: Just click "See this example in diagrams.net" below the example diagram at the top, then click Edit pen at the bottom and tick/untick the math typesetting under Extras to see the difference

Comment: sorry I didn't understand how to get a system of equations